# SQL Server query with date range and max function

Tags: sql-server, date

I have two tables, `TBL_TRANSACTION(NUM_ID,TRANS_DATE,TRANS_TYPE,TOTAL_SUM)` and `TBL_PERSONS(NUM_ID,NAME)`

I want to get the result of this query: select the NAME, NUM_ID and TRANS_DATE columns from two tables with the condition `(Names that don't have a transaction between the current date and DATEADD(YYYY,-1,GETDATE()))) and TRANS_TYPE=1`

```
SELECT  dbo.TBL_TRANSACTION.NUM_ID, dbo.TRANSACTION.TRANS_DATE, dbo.TBL_PERSON.NAME, dbo.TBL_PERSON.TOTAL_SUM
FROM    dbo.TBL_TRANSACTION INNER JOIN
        dbo.TBL_PERSON ON dbo.TBL_TRANSACTION.NUM_ID = dbo.TBL_PERSON.NUM_ID
WHERE  (dbo.TBL_TRANSACTION.TRANS_DATE NOT BETWEEN DATEADD(yyyy, - 1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()) AND TRANS_TYPE =1
```

However, I'm receiving no result from the above.

Comment: Script seems ok and the filter logic as well. Can you put some sample data with your expected output? May be there are nothing meeting your filter logic to show.

Comment: Please can you give us more details about the schema? Are you sure `NUM_ID` is the correct column to join on? Sounds like it could be PK column of each table, and therefore `TBL_TRANSACTION` probably has a `Person_ID` or similar

Answer (score 1):

Some adjustment in date filtering made in this below query. Can you check with this-

```
SELECT T1.NUM_ID, 
       T1.TRANS_DATE, 
       T2.NAME, 
       T2.TOTAL_SUM
FROM dbo.TBL_TRANSACTION T1
     INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_PERSON T2 ON T1.NUM_ID = T2.NUM_ID
WHERE T1.TRANS_DATE < DATEADD(yyyy, -1, GETDATE())
     AND TRANS_TYPE = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer  but there is a point that we must address is that all people have a history of transactions but I want to list the date of the last treatment or I want names of people that they  did not do any transaction  of type 1 in a last year begin  from today's date

Comment: Can you add some sample data with your expected output?